# Mongodb on Ubuntu -' Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE'

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Mongo has suddenly stopped working within my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, so I am trying to restart it I' am getting again and again though errors like the below:

```
 mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Τρι 2022-03-22 12:19:53 EET; 3h 46min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 27559 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27559 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have revised the mongod.conf file, which is located in /etc and includes the below:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
# engine: wiredTiger
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 23654
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Also the mongod.service located in /lib/systemd/system:

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have also changed ownership using the below commands according to [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongod-service-main-process-exited-code-exited-status-1-failure/113739) post:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-23654.sock
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

I have checked the folders and removed .lock files from /var/lib/mongodb/ which now looks like below:

```
 /var/lib/mongodb$ ls
    collection-0-2356690320700739995.wt   collection-2-2356690320700739995.wt  collection-8-5563536140699528517.wt  index-15-5563536140699528517.wt  index-5-5563536140699528517.wt  _mdb_catalog.wt    WiredTiger.wt
    collection-0-5563536140699528517.wt   collection-2-5563536140699528517.wt  diagnostic.data                      index-1-5563536140699528517.wt   index-6-2356690320700739995.wt  sizeStorer.wt
    collection-10-5563536140699528517.wt  collection-4-2356690320700739995.wt  index-10-2356690320700739995.wt      index-21-5563536140699528517.wt  index-7-5563536140699528517.wt  storage.bson
    collection-12-5563536140699528517.wt  collection-4-5563536140699528517.wt  index-11-5563536140699528517.wt      index-3-2356690320700739995.wt   index-9-2356690320700739995.wt  WiredTiger
    collection-14-5563536140699528517.wt  collection-6-5563536140699528517.wt  index-1-2356690320700739995.wt       index-3-5563536140699528517.wt   index-9-5563536140699528517.wt  WiredTigerLAS.wt
    collection-20-5563536140699528517.wt  collection-8-2356690320700739995.wt  index-13-5563536140699528517.wt      index-5-2356690320700739995.wt   journal                         WiredTiger.turtle
```

According to a previous post I had once enabled wiredTiger engine from mongod.conf but have now changed it back to the .conf shared above. Should I remove these files as well from this directory?

Finally, I have also checked the firewall for this port I am trying to use, it seems active.
Have no idea what I should fix I have read lots of related posts but haven't done yet...

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue running MongoDB on centOS and reoccurred on restart, process should be similar on Ubuntu;

run `cat /etc/mongod.conf` and ensure all referenced paths are available and owned by the MongoDB user

In my case the missing directory/file was

```
pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
```

create files and folders where missing e.g

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
sudo touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

give correct ownership

```
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
```

start and check status

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-23654.sock
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

have you user mongodb? check it `cat /etc/passwd |grep mongod`

```
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-23654.sock
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/log/mongodb
```

may be you need to chown them like this-> mongod.